# Firefox won't sense new service worker is available whereas Chrome does

Tags: service-worker

I’m in FF 110.0.1, upgrading my web-app to a PWA.

I can't get Firefox to use the new service worker, whereas it works fine in Chrome.

In Chrome it successfully installs the service worker the first time around, prompts the user when a new service worker has been uploaded, and the installation, activation and page reload works fine i.e. the new service worker installs and activates fine, and any cache changes I need to make work fine in Chrome. I even managed to get the prompt for the user to install the PWA to work.

Firefox never seems to see that the service worker has been changed - the ‘updatefound’ listener never triggers, whereas is does in Chrome.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Here's the service worker:

```
var staticCacheName = 'static';
var version = 'v1::90';
console.log("Hello there, this message is sent by a service worker " + version);

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    console.log("Service worker installed");
    event.waitUntil(updateStaticCache());
  });    

  //if the browser detects that this is a new service worker, our app js will tell this new sw to activate (via "// tell new service worker to register itself")
  self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    if (event.data === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
        console.log("skipWaiting 1");
        self.skipWaiting();
        console.log("skipWaiting 2");
    }
});

  self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
    console.log("Service worker ACTIVATE");
    event.waitUntil(
      caches.keys()
        .then(function (keys) {
          return Promise.all(keys
            .filter(function (key) {
                console.log("Cache version: " + key.indexOf(version));
              return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
            })
            .map(function (key) {
              return caches.delete(key);
            })
          );
        })
    );
  });

  function updateStaticCache() {
    console.log("updateStaticCache()");
    return caches.open(version + staticCacheName)
      .then(function (cache) {
        return cache.addAll([
          '/offlineScreen.html',
          '/js/js01.js',
          '/js/js02.js',
          '/imgs/songbookdb-PWA-icon-512.png',
          '/imgs/songbookdb-PWA-icon-192.png',
          '/imgs/icon-ios-512.png'          
        ]);
      });
  };

 self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    console.log('Handling fetch event for', event.request.url);

    event.respondWith(            
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Found response in cache:', response);

                return response;
            }

            console.log('No response found in cache. About to fetch from network...');

            return fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
                console.log('Response from network is:', response);

                return response;
            }).catch(function (error) {                    
                console.error('Fetching failed:', error);

                return caches.match('/offlineScreen.html');
            });
        })
    );
});
```

And my js:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async event => {
    
    function invokeServiceWorkerUpdateFlow(registration) {              
        conf("There's an update for SongbookDB - Install now?", 'updateServiceWorker', registration);
    }

    // check if the browser supports serviceWorker at all
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

        console.log("service workers supported in browser");
        // wait for the page to load
        window.addEventListener('load', async () => {

            // register the service worker from the file specified
            navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceWorker.js");      
            //const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js'); 
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();

            if (registration) { 
                
                console.log("service worker checks");

                // ensure the case when the updatefound event was missed is also handled
                // by re-invoking the prompt when there's a waiting Service Worker
                if (registration.waiting) {
                // invokeServiceWorkerUpdateFlow(registration)
                }

                // detect Service Worker update available and wait for it to become installed
                registration.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
                    console.log("service worker update found");
                    if (registration.installing) {
                        // wait until the new Service worker is actually installed (ready to take over)
                        console.log("service worker installing");

                        registration.installing.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                            if (registration.waiting) {
                                console.log("service worker waiting");
                                // if there's an existing controller (previous Service Worker), show the prompt
                                if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                                    invokeServiceWorkerUpdateFlow(registration)
                                } else {
                                    // otherwise it's the first install, nothing to do
                                    console.log('Service Worker initialized for the first time')
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })

                let refreshing = false;

                // detect controller change and refresh the page
                navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
                    if (!refreshing) {
                        window.location.reload()
                        refreshing = true
                    }
                })

                // For prompting user to install
                let deferredPrompt; // This variable will save the event for later use.
                window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
                    console.log('install prompt');
                // Prevents the default mini-infobar or install dialog from appearing on mobile
                //e.preventDefault();
                // Save the event because you'll need to trigger it later.
                deferredPrompt = e;
                // Show your customized install prompt for your PWA
                // Your own UI doesn't have to be a single element, you
                // can have buttons in different locations, or wait to prompt
                // as part of a critical journey.
                //showInAppInstallPromotion();
                });
            }

        })
    }   
            
    function showResult(text) {
        //document.querySelector("output").innerHTML = text;
        console.log(text);
    }   

});
```

Thank you